# Can't get ajax call with parameters to hit my C# function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

Ajax:

```
var test = "test";

$.ajax(
{
  type: "POST",
  url: "project/function",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  data: { input: test },
  success: function (response) {
    $("#lblMsg").text(response.d);
  },
  failure: function (response) {
    alert(response.d);
  }
});
```

C# function:

```
[WebMethod]
public void function(string input)
{
}
```

The connection is made successfully when I don't include a parameter. I have tried different single and double quote permutations of the 'data' portion of the ajax call, to no avail.

I have also tried setting the dataType to "text" with similar results.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you able to get it to work from Postman? Please load the Developer Tools in Chrome (Network tab) and show us the request being made (including the URL and payload being sent).

Comment: I am new to ajax and jquery so I am not familiar with best practices yet.

Comment: Did you try json.stringify ?             data: JSON.stringify({ input: test }),

Comment: What page are you sending the request from?

Comment: I would suggest not to send the data as JSON, just remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` . Also currently your function is `void` so even if the ajax call succeeds you won't get any actual response data.

Comment: @ADyson that fixed it, thank you. If you submit that as an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: @ChasetopherB done, thanks

Comment: @ChasetopherB P.S. I forgot to add, are you aware that there is no such function as "failure" in jquery ajax? The correct option to specify a callback in case of problems is "error". At the moment your code will do nothing when the method fails. Also the "error" callback does not include a property called `d` in the response, instead you'll get an XHR object - the contents of it are explained in the documentation. I see this mistake quite often on here, maybe there is some junk tutorial online somewhere using it. You can check all the valid options etc here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @ChasetopherB and the reason "dataType" didn't work is because that's a hint to jQuery about what the data type of the _response_ will be, not the type of data in the _request_ - that's controlled by contentType, as you've seen in my answer. Again, the jQuery documentation explains it all.

Comment: I am looking into that now, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you shouldn't send your data as JSON. Just remove the

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

and jQuery will serialise the data into normal url-encoded form data format, which is what the WebMethod is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

try this one may be resolve your issue

var test = "test";

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "project/function",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          datatype: "json",
          data:JSON.stringify({ 'input': test }),
          success: function (response) {
         $("#lblMsg").text(response.d);
  },
  failure: function (response) {
    alert(response.d);
  }
  });
});
```